# How to assign custom attribute to Exchange Online Mailbox using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

My task is to assign [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-custom-attributes?view=exchserver-2019&viewFallbackFrom=exchonline-ww) to mailbox in Exchange online using Graph API. Problem is that I cannot find endpoint corresponding to this attribute. It should be possible to set this attribute via Graph API because it could be done with powershell : `Set-Mailbox $UserName -CustomAttribute5 $sisSchool -AddressBookPolicy $sisSchool`

Maybe some of you have done something similar and could help me ? :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it was then, but since at least 09/16/2022 it is possible to add or update this custom data in the form of extension attributes using HTTP requests and from code on `User` resources.

To answer your question, you need to send a PATCH request to the Users endpoint while including a JSON with your data. An example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}

{
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute5": "myCustomAttribute",
    }
}
```

You can read more about creating and editing extension attributes in the Microsoft Graph API documentation:

- [Creating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) users
- [Adding custom data to resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=http)
- [Extension attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-1.0)